Can we ask for more discussion moderators to speed up the cleaning in discussions?
A moderator reminded me in SOCVR about the fact that they are not obligated to moderate content in Discussions, as quoted from here,

All Stack Overflow site moderators also have access to all Discussions moderation functions, and are welcome to moderate as they see fit, but are not obligated to do so.

I understand that SO moderators are volunteering to clean up mess in Discussions and I highly appreciate their time and effort for doing so.
I also learned about the existence of Discussions moderators. With an increasing concern of spam posting(disclosure: a post written by me) and illegal content, more efficient moderation/cleaning is required.
As pointed out in Support programmatic detection and flagging of spam and rude/abusive content in Collectives Articles and Discussions (WebSocket and SE API endpoints), programmatic moderation is not (yet) available for Discussions. Intuitively, more manual moderation is required to clean up spam and illegal content promotion waves.
So, may I have your insights on:

Is more Discussions moderators needed?

If so, is there any plan to recruit more Discussions moderators?



If they provided API access for it, Charcoal would probably catch and destroy most of it without SO mods having to do extra work.

For Users posting an Answer, would be handy if you could mention if you are (currently) a 'Discussions' Mod. Yes, there is a List of current 'Discussions' Mods available ("As of March 21, 2024, the current Discussions moderators are: Abdulla Nilam, Dalija Prasnikar, Laurel, M--, Thomas Markov."), but that List is apparently not maintained and not accurate (anymore), and maybe not complete... (Dalija for example has since become a Diamond Mod, and therefore doesn't need to be mentioned in that List...)

@chivracq The list isn't inaccurate. It exactly matches the people who have write access to the Discussions moderation room. (There are of course some other SO mods who participate in moderation, but none of them were technically appointed as Discussion mods specifically.)

@Laurel, OK, Thanks, good to know... My "point" is that it's not very handy to have to check some Help-page to find out if each Answer was posted by a User in their quality as a 'Discussions' Mod or Flagger or just a normal User... // And from a "historical" point of view, when reading this current Thread in a few years from now, that distinction will probably be even more difficult to establish, as the List will then have probably changed... (Well, if 'Discussions' still exists by then, oops...)

If you read anything else in that discussion you would know that moderators don't want to moderate discussions

@Starship Discussions require immediate moderation tooling, rep requirements and rate limiting

Is there even a point?
Discussions seems like busywork. SO should just step up and finally decide whether they should keep it, and if so, provide API access, so we do not have to do this manually.
Alternatively, just shut it down.
Hiring more janitors at the garbage dump to clean around the trash is a symptom, indicating something is not right.
If SO is really happy with the current situation, I suggest we stop flagging. I am certainly seriously considering this.

I agree that all these are effective measures to address the root cause(s). It could be just my feeling that they are yet to be available/viable for various reasons right now so I am just trying to propose something to stop the bleeding.

I'm saying that it may be time to stop mopping the blood and actually stop the bleeding. There is a whole host of problems with Discussions and SE not addressing any of them is the real issue here. Spam is just the most visible thing. Discussions is not built with community moderation in mind. If it was, it'd have been transparent. I can't see a deleted post, which means I can't flag first, for fear the post's content will disappear. I can't even see my flags. Heck, I can't retract flags. I've hear the flag experience is atrocious on the mod side, as well. If that's SE's vision, I'm out.

"If SE are really happy with the current situation, I suggest we stop flagging. I am certainly seriously considering this." I switched to this stance yesterday, after I got fed up of raising a spam flag every 10-15 minutes to those bloody "leaked" videos... (Oh look, there's 2 more now!) "Alternatively, just shut it down." Yep, I completely agree.

In between the noise and the garbage there are some genuinely good discussions so I hope they step up. It's here, you've built it so... might as well see how far it can be taken. If done properly it might take some pressure off of Q&A which already would be a win in my book. But jebus Stack Inc... give some sign you care. Just anything.

Shoot, I stopped flagging things there months ago.

@ThomA I'm seriously considering stopping too. Why don't we make a official collective strike from flagging/moderating discussions. That seems to be the only way to get SE to listen.

I honestly think that is the only way, @Starship . That's more or less what happened in the flood of '24, there was so much spam that the community couldn't do anything about it, so nothing did happen. The CMs had to get involved and even then they deleting them slower than they were being posted.

@ThomA What exactly is the flood of 2024? The mass spam wave on WebApps? Also, if you (and clearly many other users) support a strike, let's do it. Let's start drafting an open letter like last year and then announce it on Meta.

See this post @Starship . Spam was being generated at about a rate of 3 a minute for several days.

@ThomA Why didn't SE temporarily shut down posting like did during the massive spam wave on WebApps (similar number of spam posts to that wave)

Because Discussions is an abandoned child, @Starship . The fact it's happenimg again, but at a slower speed, is evidence of that; [so] don't care and don't learn their lessons.

As of now, the issue is not (at least entirely)  that we have too few moderators for Discussions. Multiple Discussions moderators have stopped handling less serious flags for different reasons (whether it's personal time constraints or else). In my opinion, until the concerns are addressed, adding more moderators is akin to taking a painkiller rather looking for a cure.
We have been promised to get statistics on Discussions months ago. We have also not seen CMs to be involved with the process recently. All the other issues that were laid out before are still at large (low quality, no API, not included in SEDE, etc.). Moreover, none of the sensible feature requests that would help to alleviate the issues are implemented (such as reputation threshold for posting a discussion). To rub salt in the wound, downvotes were removed which made moderation harder; that feature was implemented despite the pushbacks by community and moderators.
If SO is not willing to give the volunteer firefighters an extinguisher, I'd say let it burn. At this point, unless we see some drastic changes, the best outcome would be getting rid of Discussions altogether.

Discussions mods are aware of the situation. I support the request to increase the minimum reputation limit for starting a discussion to 20 and believe this is the only effective way that can reduce spam. Currently, over 100 new accounts join SE each day solely for spam.
We've already noticed a few active participants in Discussions and have had talked about them joining the Discussions moderator group.
You can check out the current Discussion moderators and current Site moderators.
FYI: Currently, the Discussions flag queue is cleared ;)

Those talks about adding new mods are a couple of months old at this point. My personal take is that we are past that point. As VLAZ said, we don't need more janitors. We need better vacuum cleaners. p.s. anyway, it's good that we have 2 different takes from Discussion-mods on this. Cheers.

"FYI: Current Q is cleared ;)" This speaks volumes of how poor the quality is in Discussions; I don't doubt many of those flags were "Not suitable for discussions" from myself, however, the fact that almost 100 posts were deleted since yesterday demonstrates how awful the quality of the content (not the spam) is as well in Discussions. More moderators won't help improve quality; on boarding would (of which there is literally none).

@ThomA don't get me wrong, the quality is atrocious, but the only reason that we had 100 discussions removed in a day is that some of us stopped handling the flags (I explained why, see my answer) and Abdulla had to take a break, but handled everything upon coming back. Honestly we don't need to count how many posts are deleted in a day or two to figure out how bad this is going.

Even so, I don't think those Discussions were that old, @M-- , maybe a week at most? Admittedly, as well, the last week or so, there really feels like there's been an increase in garbage to that area of the site. There's been so many code only dumps.

@ThomA I saw some up to 3 weeks old

Will future discussion moderators be elected or appointed (if so by who)? Also I'd say that it speaks volumes that 70% or so of the discussions that we live last night from the past 2 weeks are now deleted. And there was no spam live last night...

@Starship a couple of us handled spam flags as we saw them (I personally stopped handling NSFD flags 10 days ago or so). Abdulla (for the most part) took care of rest of the flags (including a couple of my own). Would you clarify on "speaks volumes" part? is there a typo here: "70% or so of the discussions that we live last night"? What does it speak about in volume?

@M-- I meant were live. It means that even excluding spam (your a discussion mod so you could check exactly but I think I heard somewhere that spam to good discussions is a ratio of like 4 to 1), the vast majority of posts shouldn’t even be there. It meant that just about all of discussions is a mess. Imagine if 70% of SO for 2 weeks needed closure, butwasnt closed.

@Starship we don't have any stats on SPAM/Discussions (we've been asking for stats for a while). I don't even know the total number of posts that were deleted (spam, aigc, nsfd, etc.). We simply don't have the tools to get such stats or effectively monitor the space. But I don't believe that 80% of the posts are spam. What I can believe is that well more than 50% of posts (especially these days) are not suitable for discussions, one way or another.

@M-- OK, "NSFD" = "Not Suitable For Discussions", I got that one. But I can't get my head around "AIGC"...? Even after looking at all the Flags available in 'Discussions' for Posts and Replies and trying to come up with stg around Abusive/Inappropriate/Guidelines/Content/Conduct/Code..., I can't come up with some plausible meaning for "AIGC"...?

@chivracq AI generated content
